# Algebra trick question: quotient/factor group isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ where $[G:H]=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think this might be a trick question, even if it is I am still not sure how to write it.

Let G be a group

Let H be a subgroup of G

I wish to show that if $|G:H|=n$ with $n>1$ then G has a quotient (or factor to some) group $G/N$ which is isomorphic to a subgroup $I$ of the Symmetric group $S_n$ with $|I|>1$

I'm not actually sure what N is, I think it is a typo for H. If it is supposed to be H then (this is the bit I am not sure how to write)

I want to say something like $|G:H|$ is the number of left cosets of H in G, and the quotient group is just the group of them, if that group is of order N then **of course it is** isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group on n items, the symmetric group contains every group as a subgroup we could have on n things.

If $N$ is intended, this usually denotes a normal subgroup, I am not sure how to interpret the question.

If you can interpret this correctly please do say how you interpreted it, hints are great when you are stuck on the question, not reading the question.

I don't think my "of course it is isomorphic to a subgroup" is the answer, it is from the wrong chapter's part (Rings Fields and Groups) to be so trivial.

Comment: The formulation means that there is some normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ (note that $n$ can be smaller than $|G|$, so $G$ itself need not be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$). Also, it can happen that $N$ is properly contained in $H$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft it looks like it is supposed to read $N$, I suspect from looking at it now that $I=G/N$ (the first isomorphism theorem) might come into play, given I can find a homomorphism with the image I, and kernel N. (kernels are normal subgroups, it is in the right form). Might I have a clue about how to express this? I am not sure what to do without an operation to say "look this is the kernel" on. (IE, general case)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "express this". The map that gives you the kernel can be described quite explicitly.

Comment: this has been already discussed here... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481880/let-h-subset-g-with-gh-n-then-existsk-leq-h-with-k-unlhd-g-such-tha

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft how exactly?

Comment: The map just sends an element of $G$ to the element of $S_n$ (identified with permutations of the cosets of $H$ in $G$) that acts as that element does on the cosets (by multiplication from the left).

Comment: $N$ is definitely not a typo for $H$. I cannot see any ambiguity in the question at all, but perhaps I am biased.

Comment: @DerekHolt it is unlike Allenby not to define everything in a question and given my book is second edition it is unlikely to be a typo. It's a nice little investigation regardless to find out if N actually changes depending on H, it made the question more enjoyable.

Comment: But you are asked to prove that *there exists* a quotient $G/N$ with various properties. So of course $N$ is not defined in the question -  the main point of the exercise is for you to define $N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt not sure if I agree, as I said before Allenby's questions are usually VERY specific and well defined, I'll move on. I had a glance at Lang's undergraduate algebra but it doesn't cover this topic, I'll check Fraleigh's when I get home. - Now I can't post an answer if I get to one.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what you are talking about. In what way are Allenby's questions relevant to this discussion?

Comment: @DerekHolt it's from his book, Rings Fields and Groups.

Comment: Really? What a strange coincidence!

Comment: I don't think so. I think good questions propagate, trust me on this. My hatred of lectures means all I do really is read books (which I enjoy, this isn't a complaint) but there are a lot of duplicate questions about, pardon the pun. I'll repost when I get the answer, for now I've moved on to the next question, the world doesn't pause when it gets stuck, why should I?